# Stop Jest from running tests on TS files and only on JS files

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I can't get Jest, using the command `npm test` in my program to stop running tests on my TS files. I only want to run them on JS files.

```
 PASS  Views/Shared/Global.unit.test.js (14.83s)
 FAIL  Views/Shared/Global.unit.test.ts
```

I've got this in my package.json file:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        ...,
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.11",
        "jest": "^24.7.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest"
    }
}
```

I have written the tests in typescript and only want the tests to run the js. I've looked everywhere, but all I find are ways to add support for TS testing. I want it to only run on my .js files.

Anyone had this issue or know a fix?

Answer (score 6):

After several hours of searching and messing with Jest documentation and settings, I finally found how to pick only the files you want Jest to look for. Add the "jest" field to the package.json file settings:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        ...,
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.11",
        "jest": "^24.7.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest"
    },
     "jest": {
         "testMatch": [
             "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[j]s?(x)"
         ]
    }
}
```

This needs to be added to your package.json file. This is in the [Jest Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testmatch-array-string). In the regex above you need to change the `.[jt]s` just `.[j]s`, removing the "t".

Answer (score 6):

or in `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  testMatch: ["**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js"],
  ...
};
```